# Reduce with for all and implies

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, inequalities, constraint

I have the following question.

```
p1 = a (1 - c + a)
p2 = b (1 - c - b)/((1 - b)^2)
v1 = (x^1.5 - 3*x)*p1
v2 = x*p2
```

I want to find x ranges which makes v1>v2 under the value of a and b making p1=p2. Here, 00. So I tried

```
Reduce[ForAll[{a, b, c}, Implies[p1 == p2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a < 1 && b < 1 && c < 1, v1 - v2 > 0]] && x > 0, x, Reals]
```

Then it doesn't work. I need your help.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `Reduce` produces the correct answer, although it is a bit slow: `x > 16.`  (I assume that you really do want `{a, b, c}` to be restricted to the range `{0, 1}`, as indicated in the argument of `Reduce`.)

Another way to look at the this problem is to ask for how `{p1, p2}` behave in this range of `{a, b, c}`.  First, determine `c` such that `p1 == p2`

```
Solve[(p1 == p2), c][[1, 1]] // Simplify
(* c -> ((-1 + b) (a (-1 + b) + a^2 (-1 + b) + b))/(a (-1 + b)^2 - b) *)
```

and plot `p1`

```
Plot3D[If[(1 > (c /. %) > 0), p1 /. %, Null], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0 - 2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "b", "p"}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 AxesStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}]
```

[image]

Because, `p1` is positive throughout the range of parameters, `v1 > v2` can be written as `x^1.5 - 3*x > x`.

```
Reduce[{x^1.5 - 3*x > x}, x, Reals]
(* x > 16. *)
```

as before.